# Prevent Blinking when updating Gridview

Tags: flutter, gridview

I am implementing a Gridview.builder with a list. The list gets updated on user's actions, my problem is the following: UI-wise, when the gridview is rebuilt it blinks briefly, I would like a smoothless experience for my users.

Is there a way to prevent gridview from rebuilding what has already been built, and extend with the new items or at least hide the blinking effect?

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<http.Response>(
              future: asyncListChildrenFilesResponse,
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                    snapshot.hasData) {

                  final http.Response response = snapshot.data!;
                  return MyGridView(response);

[...]
```

MyGridView

```dart
Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: GridView.builder(
                addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                controller: _scrollController, // trigger async function that will   setState(() => files.addAll(newFiles)); with newFiles coming from another http.Response
                cacheExtent: 1000,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: files.length,
```

I have simplified the files I am working with on purpose, let me know if I am missing something!

Comment: You can try increasing `cacheExtent`, but for not to rebuild it at all you can go for SingleChildScrollView,could effect the the performance, I think it would be better to include your sample code for this. Most cases, we keep calling the api during build on StreamBuilder/FutureBuild which cause this.

Comment: I am already using cache extent. So the solution would be to get rid off the futurebuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to prevent the blinking effect by using [`GridView.count`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.count.html) instead of `GridView.builder`